# Having trouble finding a specific string (with wildcards in the middle) using regex and python

Tags: python, regex, search

**Sample Text:**

> "UNCKEV\nPumpkins 10/1/20-2030\nRunners\nha\nH[ 12 ]\nA[ O
>   ]\nKNOWLEDGI\nPLA\nDISTRIBUTION\nHOME TEAM\nPINK VISITING
>   TEAM\nBLANCHE BUREAU NATIONAL\nJAUNE \u00c9C\nALE\nPR\u00c9CISER LES
>   DE\nSEULEMENT\nOFF\nSORTIE\nSTART\nD\u00c9BUT\nON\nRETOUR\nPER\nP\u00c9R.\nMIN\nSERV\nPURG\nOFFENCE\nINFRACTION\nDUR\u00c9E\nNo.\nDU\nNeinterferCACE
>   =\n188 Cross clicak 3\n1010hgh shicle\n"

**I'm trying to extract H[(wildcard)] and A[(wildcard)] from the sample text, separately.**

If I use `x = re.search('H\[.*\]', ocr[0])` it finds the whole string `H[ 12 ]\nA[ O ]`

If I use `'A\[.*\]'` it will find A[ O ] by itself - but I can't seem to just find H[ 12 ].

Comment: Use `'H\[.*?\]'` or better `'H\[[^]]*\]'` https://regex101.com/r/ZqdCvz/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with greedy qualifiers in Python's regular expression library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html . ctrl-F to find: *greedy*.

The greedy qualifier `*` wants to match as many characters as possible. To make it non-greedy, a `?` qualifier should be introduced. The remedied regex can thus be: `H\[.*?\]`

To make this search work for any capitalized alphabet character, try: `[A-Z]\[.*?\]`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use a non greedy pattern:

```
\b[AH]\[.*?\]
```

Python script:

```
inp = "UNCKEV\nPumpkins 10/1/20-2030\nRunners\nha\nH[ 12 ]\nA[ O ]\nKNOWLEDGI\nPLA\nDISTRIBUTION\nHOME TEAM\nPINK VISITING TEAM\nBLANCHE BUREAU NATIONAL\nJAUNE \u00c9C\nALE\nPR\u00c9CISER LES DE\nSEULEMENT\nOFF\nSORTIE\nSTART\nD\u00c9BUT\nON\nRETOUR\nPER\nP\u00c9R.\nMIN\nSERV\nPURG\nOFFENCE\nINFRACTION\nDUR\u00c9E\nNo.\nDU\nNeinterferCACE =\n188 Cross clicak 3\n1010hgh shicle\n"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[AH]\[.*?\]', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['H[ 12 ]', 'A[ O ]']
```

Comment: Both regexes do not match. I do not understand why you posted two different ones without any explanation. Additionally, none of them capture the required values.
https://regex101.com/r/gcZZzW/1

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`H\[ (\w+) \](?:.|\n)+A\[ (\w+) \]`

If you know that the H and A parameter will always be separated by a newline and nothing else, replace `(?:.|\n)+` with only `\n`.

I'm not sure what the contents of your H and A variables can be but `\w` should capture most of them.

Comment: This does not provide a flexible answer to the OP.